# После завершения основного потока программы, JVM продолжает выполянть непонятные потоки

Tags: java, многопоточность

Использую proprietary библиотеку.

В классе `main()` создаю экземляр `Thread-safe configurated` класса из этой библиотеки.

Затем, в мультитрейдинге, используя этот единственный экземляр, запускаю методы этого класса с разными параметрами.

Каждому созданному потоку делаю `join()`.
По окончанию этих методов и метода main() имею необходимый результат.

Однако даже после окончания метода `main()` в командной строке продолжает мигать курсор, говорящий о том что программа продолжает выполняться.

Полагаю, что это потоки, запущенные методами этого класса (хотя сами методы завершили работу!).

Как я могу программно завершить работу этих потоков? К исходникам доступа не имею, от этой библиотеки отказаться не могу.

Comment: так как библиотека неизвестна, то рекомендую почитать документацию к ней и поспрашивать разработчиков этой библиотеки. Если и это не поможет, то посмотреть отладчиком/профайлером/дизамссемблером и разобраться. Если и это не поможет - написать библиотеку самому. В случае, если и после этого решение не будет найдено - пойти в другую компанию.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Краткая справка о потоках в Java. Потоки бывают двух видов:

- Daemon (демон) - служебный поток
- Основной поток (не-демон)

JVM завершает работу программы, когда все ее потоки, не являющиеся демонами, завершены. Как только завершается последний не-демон-поток, все демоны сразу уничтожаются. Поэтому, чтобы гарантированно завершить все потоки после завершения вашего основного потока, нужно, чтобы они были демонами. И вот тут есть удобная штука: демон-поток может порождать только демоны. Поэтому вам нужно в мейне создать новый поток, сделать его демоном, и уже в нём запускать сторонние библиотеки. Когда ваш главный поток отработает, все демоны тут же завершатся. Пример, как это сделал я, когда столкнулся с такой же проблемой:

```
Thread daemon = new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                bot.init(log); //в этом методе запускаются потоки сторонних библиотек
            }
        };
        daemon.setDaemon(true); //делаем поток демоном
        daemon.start(); //запускаем. Все потоки, порожденные внутри него,
            //будут тоже демонами, и не будут мешать завершению программы
```

Только необходимо учитывать, что как только ваш `main` завершит работу, все демоны будут завершены (если нет других не-демонов). Советую основательно подумать, как лучше разделить потоки на основные и служебные, в случае крайней необходимости можно подождать завершения демона с помощью известного вам `join()`.